# How to Connect C++ to Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

I've tried to link between C++(Win32) and MATLAB(win64).I added the path under the VC++ directories and also added "libeng.lib libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib" under linker>>input>. 
but I got the error: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engOpen referenced in function _main.

any idea to solve this problem?

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "engine.h"
#include "mex.h"

#pragma comment (lib,"libmat.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"libmx.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"libmex.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"libeng.lib")

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    Engine *m_pEngine;
    m_pEngine=engOpen("null");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you check if your Matlab and C++ are running on the same platform (32bit or 64bit)?

Comment: my MATLAB is 64bit  and c++ is 32bit which are both running in my widows 64bit

Comment: You could try changing the path for VC++ to target 64bit and see if that help you with the issue: [How to Change VC++ to target 64bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx)

Comment: thanks a lot, it is solved now, but I got another error: as "the code execution cannot proceed because libmx.dll and libeng.dll was not found"  what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check if both Matlab and C++ are running on the same version (32bit or 64bit). You can change the settings on VC++ to run on 64 using this information from Microsfot: [How to: Configure Visual C++ Projects to Target 64-Bit Platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx)

For the Error related to **libmx.dll was not found** try the following:

1. The DLL is located in MATLABROOT/bin/win32. Add this location to the
   system environmental variable "Path".
2. This error may also indicate that the file "libmx.dll" is missing from your MATLAB installation directory. This can occur if certain antivirus software is installed and it quarantines the file. To resolve the issue, open the antivirus software and restore the quarantined file "libmx.dll".

Hope this helps; Cheers

Comment: I can find these files in MATLABROOT/bin/win32. How can I add this location to the system environmental?